# How to pass parameters to the script while calling them inside the provisioner

Tags: powershell, terraform

I want to pass the variables inside my terraform script when I call the PowerShell script inside "provisioner". I have used the following code.

```
resource "null_resource" "example2" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
     command= "-azureAplicationId 0000 -azureTenantId 0000 -azureSecret 000 > C:\\Users\\Boopathi Kumar\\Downloads\\poscript1.ps1"
     interpreter = ["powershell.exe", "-File"]
  }
}
```

Comment: See if using an external provider as described in this blog post helps: https://thegrayzone.co.uk/blog/2017/03/external-terraform-provider-powershell/

Comment: @trebleCode I tried the external provider it works. But the issue that bothers me with using an external provider is that we have to rewrite the PowerShell code to produce JSON output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
resource "null_resource" "example2" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
     command= "C:\\Users\\Boopathi Kumar\\Downloads\\poscript1.ps1 -azureAplicationId ${var.appId} -azureTenantId ${var.tenantId} -azureSecret ${var.secret}"
     interpreter = ["powershell.exe", "-File"]
  }
}
```

Comment: It throws the following error:                                                                                   Error running command 'C:\Users\Boopathi Kumar\Downloads\Untitled1.ps1 -azureAplicationId xxxxxx -azureTenantId xxxxxx -azureSecret xxxxxx: exit status 4294770688. Output: Processing -File 'C:\Users\Boopathi Kumar\Downloads\Untitled1.ps1 -azureAplicationId xxxxxx -azureTenantId xxxxxx -azureSecret xxxxxx failed because the file does not have a '.ps1' extension. Specify a valid Windows PowerShell script file name, and then try again.

Comment: Try to change the interpreter to "interpreter = ["PowerShell"]"

Comment: No, it still shows the same error. I wrote the entire script inside the "command" parameter using the EOF and referenced the  parameters as provided in the terraform script.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear on the solution to the issue with passing parameters into Powershell script, important bits is to add the .\ to the relative path (with an additiona \ for escape special character as well as using -Command (and not -File):

```
resource "null_resource" "share_integrationruntime" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = ".\\Share-ADF-IntegrationRuntime.ps1 ${var.resource_group_name} ${var.data_factory_service_name}"
    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command" ]
  }
}
```